# Node TypeError: root path required

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am trying to setup a simple node/express server and I receive the following error

> TypeError: root path required

I would like to know how to fix this error.
Thanks

---

```
var nodeModulesDir = process.env.NODE_MODULES_DIR,

app.use(express.static(publicDir));
app.use("/node_modules", express.static(nodeModulesDir)); // ERROR AT THIS LINE
app.post("/uploads", onUpload);
app.delete("/uploads/:uuid", onDeleteFile);
```

Comment: How did you run your node-app ? (add command please)

Comment: Sounds like `$NODE_MODULES_DIR` isn't set...

Comment: I am running using node myfilename.js

Comment: Actually after some logging I see nodeModulesDir  as undefined

Comment: @Radex, you need set environment variable, I try it, and solved the problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

modify .bash_profile add **export NODE_MODULES_DIR=GGGGGGGGGGG**

[image]

BTW, Don't forget restart the server!

Comment: Any idea where to find .bash_profile in Codesandbox?

Answer (score 6):

Tryout this way

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

i mean use `__dirname` for get from main root path .

Comment: This worked for me, but my problem was I had to change `app.use( Express.static(__dirname));` to `app.use( Express.static(__dirname + '/'));` (add a slash)

Comment: worked perfectly when visual code studio was giving me this error during debugging

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR:**
check your **publicDir** or **nodeModulesDir** variables that you are passing.

Express uses the module [serve-static](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve-static).

so the error comes from:

```
function serveStatic (root, options) {
  if (!root) {
    throw new TypeError('root path required')
  }
   ...
}
```

> **serveStatic(root, options)**
>
> Create a new middleware function to serve
>   files from within a given root directory. The file to serve will be
>   determined by combining req.url with the provided root directory. When
>   a file is not found, instead of sending a 404 response, this module
>   will instead call next() to move on to the next middleware, allowing
>   for stacking and fall-backs.